# Calculate a lower bound for the condition number κ(A) for the matrix A.

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

We have a matrix A for which we want to give an estimate of the condition number.
We know that the system Ax = b with input b = (4, −8, 1)T has solution x = (2, 1, 0)T

We also know that a somewhat modified right-hand vector b˜ = (4, −8, 2)T solves the system A˜x = b˜, where ˜x = (8, 11, −3)T.

Comment: Strictly speaking it is not possible to do what you want to do, but the reason is subtle and I can make an educated guess as to what your instructor intends for you to do. However, you need to edit your question and include more information. How has your instructor defined the condition number of a matrix $A$? Are you familiar with the supremum property of the set of real numbers? Without answers to these questions, it is impossible to help you.